# How to update Status using IF Condition in Mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger

I'm trying to write an update trigger that will Design_Update_Status to Customized when a date is entered in Custom_Design_Update_Date field and if nothing is entered that field it should update Design_Update_Status to Standard.

As of now i am using a trigger  and this doesnot update the status correctly.

```
IF NEW.Custom_Design_Update_Date = ''
THEN
SET NEW.Design_Update_Status = 'STANDARD';
else 
SET NEW.Design_Update_Status = 'CUSTOMIZED'; 
END IF;
```

tried a lot in this, cant figure out a solution. help needed in this regard.

Thanks,
Acube.

Comment: Should that be `NEW.Custom_Design_Update_Date IS NULL` ?

Comment: i checked with NULL also , it is getting updated with CUTOMIZED not Standard. it always taking the value CUSTOMIZED

Comment: The 'NEW.Custom_Design_Update_Date IS NULL' should work as you described. Check the real value of the 'Custom_Design_Update_Date', perhaps it is not NULL